# apache problom unable to connect

Tags: apache2

When I want to open a php file that is saved in `/var/www/html/` this message is shown:

> problem loading page : unable to connect

I’ve checked all the files and their permissions...
I'm  using Ubuntu 15.04

But when i'm online,i mean there is an internet connection it works perfectly... Is it OK?!!

Please help thank you all.

Comment: Have a look at this thread [Unable to Connect Apache](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2284230) whether this helps.

Comment: Check if apache is running on port 80 with command sudo netstat -tunlep | grep :80, also share your error logs (/var/log/apache2/error.log)  and virtualhost configuration

Comment: is it ok?      tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          37723       3719/apache2

Answer (score -2):

Check `/etc/hosts` file. Check value

```
hostname 127.0.0.1
```

replace with

```
hostname <current ipaddress>
```

See below link for installation of apache, mysql and php hope this help.

Comment: Just thought I'd explain the downvote, but this doesn't seem right. It just seems like a bad copy/paste from somewhere. Also, why would you replace the `127.0.0.1` address with the `current IP address`?